# Curl followlocation not working on server

Tags: php, curl

I have a script which is working fine on my xampp and deals with the follow location just fine.

But now I have transferred it to the server and it doesn't work. I'm just receiving the `301 moved permanently`  site. My cUrl looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dir_url);
```

I have tried it with error reporting on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But it just doesn't output any errors...

Any ideas what it could be?

**Edit:**

```
//Start Curl Connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dir_url);
//read content of $url
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo curl_error ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: You use [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to get cURL errors.

Comment: thank you, I tried like I edited above. It does not output anything??

Comment: What is the url you are trying to get data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was, that a open_basedir is set in the PHP settings.

I used the function from this blog post:

http://slopjong.de/2012/03/31/curl-follow-locations-with-safe_mode-enabled-or-open_basedir-set/

Now its working!

Comment: Thank you for answer your own question and save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Some servers check for the existence of certain headers.
Probably `Accept-Language` is missing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept-Language: en-us'
));
```

Or the `referer`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $dir_url);
```